# Assembly AT&T x86 - How to compare a specific byte in a long?

Tags: assembly, utf-8, x86, byte, att

I'm writing a function in assembly that takes in an unsigned long.
This long is a UTF-8 character.

I want to check if it is a 1, 2, 3 or 4 byte UTF-8 char. So far I have this: (I've altered to code to not be affected by endianness, I think ...)

```
movl    12(%ebp),%eax   # Move long u to %eax
movl    %eax,buff       # Move long u to buff
andl    $128,buff       # &-mask 1 MSB (from LSByte)
cmpl    $0,buff         # Compare buff to 0
je      wu8_1byte       # If 0, 1 byte UTF8

movl    12(%ebp),%eax   # Move long u to %eax
movl    %eax,buff       # Move long u to buff
andl    $0xE000,buff    # &-mask 3 MSB (from byte LSByte 2)
cmpl    $0xC000,buff    # Compare the 3 MSB to binary 110
je      wu8_2byte       # If =, 2 byte UTF8

movl    12(%ebp),%eax   # Move long u to %eax
movl    %eax,buff       # Move long u to buff
andl    $0xF00000,buff  # &-mask 4 MSB (from byte MSByte 3)
cmpl    $0xE00000,buff  # Compare the 4 MSB to binary 1110
je      wu8_3byte       # If =, 3 byte UTF8

jmp     wu8_4byte       # If no, 4 byte UTF8
```

12(%ebp) is the long I want to work with. Buff is a 4 byte variable.

It works for 1byte, but not for the others.

Any tips on how I can figure out what type of UTF-8 char it is?

UTF-8 Encoding:

```
                           0xxxxxxx    # 1 byte
                  110xxxxx 10xxxxxx    # 2 byte
         1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx    # 3 byte
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx    # 4 byte
```

Comment: When you say "this long is a UTF-8 character", is it definitely encoded in a big-endian form? Because that would be unusual on Intel.

Comment: I'm note sure what endianess it is. I'm using gcc -m32 to compile it, and I test the assemby functions with C-programs.

Comment: Well the fact that you're shifting the 13 bits to test part of the leading byte tells me that you believe the long to have the UTF-8 byte sequence stored in big endian order. The architecture of your system is little endian. That's why it seems odd to me.

Comment: I altered the code for &-masking, and endianess should not have an effect on it. (And yes I was wrong, my machine is little endian, thank you for telling me). But this did not work either:  <br/>   movl    12(%ebp),%eax <br/>
 movl %eax,buff  <br/>  
 andl $128,buff   <br/> 
 cmpl $0,buff  <br/>  
 je  wu8_1byte  <br/>

Comment: **Altered the main post.**

Comment: You haven't altered the assumptions in your code. You seem to assume that if the unsigned long contains a single UTF-8 byte sequence then the byte is stored in the least significant byte, and if it contains a two byte sequence then the bytes are stored in the least significant two bytes of the `unsigned long` **but** with the first byte in the more significant byte and with the following byte in the least significant byte. This isn't strict big endian (both bytes stored in the most significant two bytes), but it is an unusual byte ordering. Are you sure that this assumption is correct?

Comment: Please, just disregard all my code and answer the title question if that makes it easier to answer. I have no idea what I'm doing, and that's why I'm here and asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't work for any of them for a simple reason.

You take a 32bit value and shift it right. Then you compare it to a constant forgetting that there's still a lot more bits left than the ones you're comparing to.

You have to and the value to only take the bits you want:

```
movl 12(%ebp),%eax
movl %eax,buff
shrb $13,buff #UTF8 2 byte looks like 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
andl $7, buff # Take only the three lowest bits
cmpl $6,buff #Therefore shift 13 spaces right and check
je wu8_2byte #if buff=6 (110 = 6)
```

I would also handle it within the register and not in a memory location to make it faster. You can also do it with just an and without any shifts.

Comment: I assumed the longs were all 0-padded from left to right. However, I tried you solution, and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how little error checking you want to do, you can simply test bits with the `test` instruction. I've assumed that the `unsigned long` has been loaded from a sequence of UTF-8 encoded bytes, least significant byte first which should be the same result as aliasing a `char*` to a `unsigned long*` on a little endian machine.

If these assumptions are wrong then you may need to alter the code accordingly - and it may be more complex as you might not know which byte is the leading byte.

E.g.

```
movl 12(%ebp),%eax
testl $128,%eax
jz wu8_1byte
testl $32,%eax     # We know that the top bit is set, it's not valid for it to be
                   # 10xxxxxx so we test this bit: 11?xxxxx
jz wu8_2byte
testl $16,%eax     # 111?xxxx
jz wu8_3byte
# Must be 4 byte
jmp wu8_4byte
```

This code snippet makes the same assumptions as your original code.

```
movl 12(%ebp),%eax

testl $0x80,%eax
jz wu8_1byte
                     # We can assume that the last byte is of the form 10xxxxxx
testl $0x7000,%eax   # Testing this bit in byte n - 1: 1?xxxxxx
jnz wu8_2byte

testl $0x700000,%eax # Testing this bit in byte n - 2: 1?xxxxxx
jnz wu8_3byte
# Must be 4 byte
jmp wu8_4byte
```

Comment: Additional optimizations that would distract from your answer: `testl $128,%eax` could be shorter by testing `%al`, or even `testl %al,%al` / `jns` to branch on the top bit of the low 8 without an immediate constant.  But `test $imm8, %al` has a special opcode, so it's still a 2B instruction.  Also, `testl $0x7000,%eax` could be `test 0x70, %ah` to save another couple bytes of machine code.  (Reading partial registers is always fine, it's writing partial registers that can lead to slowdowns.  Avoid `test $imm16, %ax`, though: 16bit operand-size with immediates causes an LCP stall)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reading up on UTF-8 and finding an easier solution:

```
cmpl    $0x7F,12(%ebp)     # Compare unsigned long to 1 byte UTF-8 max value
jbe     wu8_1byte

cmpl    $0x7FF,12(%ebp)    # Compare unsigned long to 2 byte UTF-8 max value
jbe     wu8_2byte

cmpl    $0xFFFF,12(%ebp)   # Compare unsigned long to 3 byte UTF-8 max value
jbe     wu8_3byte

cmpl    $0xFFFFFF,12(%ebp) # Compare unsigned long to 4 byte UTF-8 max value
jbe     wu8_4byte
```

The way the UTF-8 characters are encoded, the 1 byte characters has a max value of 0x7F, 2 byte max 0x7FF, 3 byte max 0xFFFF, and 4 byte max 0xFFFFFF. So by just comparing the unsigned long to these values i can determine the number of bytes needed to decode the character.

Comment: Even though I'm still not sure, where the actual data bytes lies, e.g.: in the unsigned long: xxxxxxxx(byte0) xxxxxxxx(byte1) xxxxxxxx(byte2) xxxxxxxx(byte3). Where 12(%ebp) is byte0, and 15(%ebp) is byte3. Where are the UTF-8 data bytes? Do they always start from byte0? As in a 4 byte UTF-8:  11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx & 1 byte UTF-8: 0xxxxxxx 00000000 00000000 00000000?